# PHP Doctrine 1.2 table names

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm trying to upgrade my doctrine ORM from 1.1.6 to 1.2.1 but i've enountered a BC issue with table names.

Some of my table names have several words (e.g. t_foo_bar for class FooBar) where the t_ prefix is generated automatically with:

```
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_TBLNAME_FORMAT, 't_%s');
```

This worked well in previous versions. In 1.2.1 however, it looks like doctrine is looking for t_foobar (instead of t_foo_bar with an underscore).

Do you know how to solve this without changing the table names?

Comment: hi i am using  1.2.4 version but i h=getting errors. i need configuration for that.

Answer (score 2):

In the `setTableDefinition()` method of your model you can call `$this->setTableName('t_foo_bar')` to set the table name explicitly. This is much better, as if some class gets renamed, the app will continue to work.

Comment: Yeah, that does work without setting the ATTR_TBLNAME_FORMAT attribute, meaning that the name should be set for every table. I did prefer the one line approach although that'll do.

Thanks for your prompt response!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I've got here through google. I've just started symfony and want to add symfony+doctrine app to an existing web-app.

I've found this stuff in the Doctrine docs (notice second line):

---

```
Group:
  **tableName: group_table**
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
  relations:
    Users:
      foreignAlias: Groups
      class: User
      refClass: GroupUser
```

Seems you can define table name in the yml file too.